# Custom fields on java enum not getting serialized

Tags: java, serialization, enums, custom-fields

I have a Java Enum as shown below:

```
public enum ExecutionMode {
  TYPE_A,
  TYPE_B,
  TYPE_C;

  private ExecutionMode(){} //no args constr- no really required

  private boolean incremental; //has get/set
  private String someStr;      //has get/set
}
```

I see that after deserialization, the custom fields on the enum are lost.
On reading more about it, I got the impression that enum gets deserialized into a string and hence its custom fields are ignored.

If its true, am I abusing Enum here & should just use POJO istead?
Or is there a way to serialize the custom fields (that are not part of the constructor)?

Thanks!

Comment: Go with the pojo. See link here for information about `Enum` serialization: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/serialization/relnotes15.html

Comment: One more link about enums serialization http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#enum

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the values are constant, this is better and you don't need to serialize anything

```
public enum ExecutionMode {
  TYPE_A(x,t),
  TYPE_B(y,z),
  TYPE_C(b,s)

  private boolean incremental; //has get/set
  private String someStr;      //has get/set

  ExecutionMode(boolean incremental,String someStr){
        ///... set things appropriately
  } 
}
```

If you're setting these values at runtime, my inclination would be that this shouldn't be an enum in the first place - there should be a separate POJO that perhaps contains the values as well as a reference to an enum value.

Comment: May as well make those fields `final` too if they aren't to be changed.

Comment: I wonder if this approach (with setters) would mean that the serialized enum would not contain the latest values of `incremental` or `someStr`, but instead be serialized with the defaults.

Comment: @yshavit - It won't hold the state. If you're using setters outside of the enum, it shouldn't be an enum.

Comment: That's what I would have assumed, @dfb. I suspect that's not what the OP wants, based on the original question. If it is, the OP would have provided that constructor and not had a setter.

Comment: Thanks @dfb. Thats exactly how I'd defined the enum, but now there are changes were the custom fields have to be made mutable.

Comment: And as you and @yshavit discussed- may be I should not keep it a enum anymore.

Answer (score 7):

From the [Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9):

> The final clone method in Enum ensures that enum constants can never
>   be cloned, and **the special treatment by the serialization mechanism
>   ensures that duplicate instances are never created as a result of
>   deserialization**. Reflective instantiation of enum types is prohibited.
>   Together, these four things ensure that no instances of an enum type
>   exist beyond those defined by the enum constants.

What you are asking for would create more than one instance of, say, TYPE_A. This would break enums. Enums should be immutable.

Comment: They don't have to be stateless, they just shouldn't have mutable state.

Comment: @yshavit - Thanks; I've changed the wording to "immutable" to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks @McDowell & yshavit - I think "They don't have to be stateless, they just shouldn't have mutable state." probably sums it up!